# I am getting error in Query

Tags: apex, soql

```
Hotel__c ht=[select Guest Name__c, Room Type__c from Hotel__c where Hotel Name__c=R-0005];
System.debug('play'+ht);
```

here it gives error

> Line: 1, Column: 10
> Unexpected token 'ht'.

Comment: DML are statements like `insert myList;` and `update aRecord;`. What you have here is a SOQL query. Also, unsure if this would cause the error but you're missing the single quotes around `R-0005` at the end of your query (string literals must be enclosed in single quotes).

Comment: Is it supposed to be `Guest_Name__c`, `Room_Type__c`, `Hotel_Name__c`? (Note the underscores that are not in your original post.) Be sure you are using the correct API Name of the fields and not the Field Label.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few syntax errors with the SOQL query that are causing this error to occur.

1. It looks like you are trying to [alias](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_alias.htm) the field names; however, this feature is only available for aggregate queries. To resolve this issue you'll need to remove `Guest`, `Room`, and `Hotel` from the query.
2. `R-0005` must be wrapped in single quotes since it is not a SOQL keyword.

```
Hotel__c ht=[select Name__c, Type__c from Hotel__c where Name__c='R-0005'];
System.debug('play'+ht);
```

Comment: Line: 1, Column: 13
select Name__c, Type__c from Hotel__c where ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:8 No such column 'Name__c' on entity 'Hotel__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Now i am getting this error

Comment: why it shows 'ht' is invalid